# Maintain a ThreadPool Lineage or know which Thread is accessing the Class Instance Methods

Tags: python, multithreading, fastapi, threadpoolexecutor, class-method

We have a FastAPI endpoint in which we are using `ThreadPoolExecutor` to execute 4~5 steps (methods).

Now, we have a class, let's say, `Debugger`. We are calling its methods and using its attributes as class instance only and not creating objects. For example,

```
Debugger.log_scalar({"threashold": 0.25})
Debugger.log_artifact("max_plot": "some_plot")
```

These methods add `key-values` in a dict at `class instance` of `Debugger`

Now, different methods in different files in `ThreadPoolExecutor` call these `Debugger` methods to update dict at `Debugger class instance` which is later returned by the FastAPI endpoint.

This setup is working fine for 1 request at a time, But, if we have 2 or more requests at the same time, then, the dict at `Debugger class instance` would mix-up data for different requests. How can we maintain different dict for each request at `Debugger class Instance`.

For example, let's say, we create a unique `uuid()` at the start of FastAPI request, then, **how can Debugger know that, it is being called from which request**, so that it can keep dict separately for separate requests. Let me know if any other clarification is needed.

**So, we could say, the question is, how to pass some value to a Thread and maintain its lineage. Or we could say, how to know the class is accessed from which Thread?**

Notes :-

- We could pass `uuid()` to each method via `ThreadPoolExecutor`, then, to internal other methods, then to some other methods in other files from where Debugger is called, then to `Debugger()` class as object. I think this is not a good way to do. In this approach, if a new developer is creating a new step, then he should make sure to pass `uuid()` in all his steps or files and then to `Debugger()` object
- We tried threading.local().

  For example, before ThreadPoolExecutor,

  ```
  local_data = threading.local()
  local_data.req_id = uuid()
  ```

  Then, inside Debugger class instance,

  ```
  local_data = threading.local()
  current_req_id = local_data.req_id
  ```

  But, this is giving me the error,

  ```
  AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'req_id'
  ```

  Also, If I am creating `threading.local()` variable at some common file and importing it everywhere, then also the same error. It's not necessary to do with `threading.local()`, I am just sharing what all we tried.